# Need help using java.lang.reflect.Array to sort arrays

Tags: java, arrays

An interview question was to write this method to remove duplicate element in an array.

```
public static Array removeDuplicates(Array a) {
 ...
```

return type is `java.lang.reflect.Array` and parameter is also `java.lang.reflect.Array` type.

How would this method be called for any array?

Also not sure about my implementation:

```
public static Array removeDuplicates(Array a)
{
    int end=Array.getLength(a)-1;
    for(int i=0;i<=end-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<=end;j++)
        {
            if(Array.get(a, i)==Array.get(a, j))
            {
                Array.set(a, j, Array.get(a, end));
                end--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    Array b=(Array) Array.newInstance(a.getClass(), end+1);
    for(int i=0;i<=end;i++)
        Array.set(a, i, Array.get(a, i));
    return b;
}
```

Comment: You may wish to consider sorting your array first ...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: assume array is presorted. my question is how to convert int array or any array to array type and pass as argument to this method.in interview method declaration was only given and was told to remove duplicate element.

Answer (score 0):

There are various problem with this code. Starting here:

```
 if(Array.get(a, i)==Array.get(a, j))
```

Keep in mind that those `get()` calls return **Object**. So, when you pass in an array of strings, comparing with == simply will most likely result in wrong results (because many objects that are in fact **equal** still have **different** references --- so your check returns **false** all the time!)

So, the first thing to change: use `equals()` instead of == !

The other problem is:

```
end--;
```

Seriously: you **never ever** change the variable that controls your for loop.

Instead: have another counter, like

```
int numberOfOutgoingItems = end;
```

and then decrease **that** counter!

For your final question - check the javadoc; for example for [get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get(java.lang.Object,%20int)). That reads `get(Object array, int index)`

So you *should* be able to do something like:

```
 int a[] = ...;

 Object oneValue = Array.get(a, 0);
```

for example.

**Disclaimer**. I have to admit: I don't know if the Array implementation is **smart** enough to automatically turn the elements of an int[] into an Integer object.

It could well be that **you** have to write code first to detect the exact type of array (if it is an array of int for example); to instead call `getInt()` instead of `getObject()`.

Beyond that, some further reading how to use reflection/Array can be found [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html)

Comment: thanks will keep in mind about loop and equals() .can u tell me how to pass argument while calling like i created a int [ ]a={1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,7} now how to pass this array in my method?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a different data structure such as a hashmap to detect the duplicate (O(1)) instead of looping with nested for loops (O(n^2)).  It should give you much better time complexity.

Comment: He is asking how to solve a problem **given** java.lang.reflect.Array. What point is there telling him to use other classes?

Comment: @GhostCat I guess I just made a few assumptions since it's an interview question (since there isn't any restrictions mentioned) . But you are right :)

Comment: yes they wanted me to solve using java.lang.reflect.Array as only method declaration was given and mentioned remove duplicate element from an array